# "Serve modules without publishing" equivalent in RAD 8?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, websphere, rad, eclipse-wtp

It appears as though the way RAD publishes dynamic web projects to WebSphere has changed between RAD 7.5 and RAD 8.

In RAD 7.5, content from the "WebContent" folder in a dynamic web project was served directly from that folder. So if changes were made outside of RAD, by another editor for example, the changes were reflected on the next browser refresh. There was no need to refresh the RAD project.

This behaviour is similar to Tomcat's "Serve modules without publishing" option.

In RAD8 content from the "WebContent" folder appears to be copied to a staging folder (namely **{workspace}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\**) when a publish occurs. This means if you edit the files outside of RAD you must refresh the RAD project, so it's aware of the changes, then publish so they are reflected on the server.

Is there a way to get the "Serve modules without publishing"-like behaviour back?

I've tried "Run server with resources in the workspace" to no avail. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In RAD7.5,in the Server tab where you see you application servers listed ,double click on the server that you want to change. That should bring up a page which has a server properties page. Under publishing you can see option to prevent automatic publishing. I think the option is something like "Never publish automatically".

Try the same in RAD8. ( I am telling this from the top of my head.So if you can't find it let me know.)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to prevent automatic publishing, I'm attempting to get the server to serve the content (.js files in particular) directly from the workspace (hence removing the need to publish).

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by putting an nginx proxy in front of the server which intercepts calls for any of the static files in particular paths and serves them directly from the workspace. This is less than ideal but it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Double click on server.
2. Under publish settings for `WebSphere Application Server --> select Run Server` with Resources within the workspace.

Hope this helps.